# Writing to has_many :through associations and callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Consider a "Name" model which has a required "label" attribute and an arbitrary Rails 3 model "Foo" with the following associations:

```
has_many :names, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :special_names, :through => :names, :source => :label, :conditions => { 'special_names.label' => 'special' }, :dependent => :destroy
```

Now it's possible to access the "special_names" attribute for *reading* the association, but *writing* to it fails because AR cannot infer from the condition that the "label" attribute needs to be set to "special" for all members of the "special names" association.

I attempted to use the "add_before" association callback, but that never gets called with the join model (instead the ":source" and "Foo" are used).

Any ideas on how to handle this in the model (as opposed to: using special logic in the controller to deal with this - that's how I handle it currently)?

*Edit*: (regarding the answer from [Ray Baxter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/688480/ray-baxter))

The relationship expressed **is** actually a "has_many :through" association. I'll try again, this time with a (hopefully) better example:

```
# Label is a shared entity which is used in many contexts
has_many :labels, :through => :user_labels

# UserLabel is the join model which qualifies the usage of a Label
has_many :user_labels, :dependent => :destroy

# special_user_labels is the topic of this question
has_many :special_user_labels, :through => :user_labels, :source => :label, :conditions => { 'user_labels.descriptor' => 'special' }, :dependent => :destroy
```

Comment: When you say writing, do you mean, something like, `foo.special_names.build` ?

Comment: How is this a `has_many :through`? Isn't this just a `has_many` with conditions?

Comment: jpemberthy: yes - specifically I want to use form attributes and mass assignment in the same way as I would with hbtm associations (..._ids).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution (thanks x0f@Freenode) - one needs to split the 'special' associations in two. `has_many :special_user_labels, :through => :user_labels, :source => :label, :conditions => { 'user_labels.descriptor' => 'special' }, :dependent => :destroy` becomes

1) `has_many :special_labels, :class_name => 'UserLabel', :conditions => { :descriptor => 'special' }, :dependent => :destroy`

2) `has_many :special_user_labels, :through => :special_labels, :source => :label, :dependent => :destroy`

Works for reading & writing as well as a seamless replacement for (scoped) hbtm associations.

Answer (score 2):

If my comment above is correct, and you aren't doing a `has_many :through`, this works:

```
has_many :special_names, :class_name => 'Name', :conditions => {:label => 'special'}, :dependent => :destroy
```

so now you can do

```
foo = Foo.create
foo.special_name.build
```

and `ActiveRecord` will correctly instantiate your special_name with the `label` attribute having the value `"special"`.

Comment: I have added another example to my original question - thanks for the followup!